# What does "elaborate a point from one St. Patrick's day to the next" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I am studying for the GRE, and this sentence came out:

> The professor's volubility knows no bounds; he could talk through a hurricane and elaborate a point from one St. Patrick's day to the next.

I can understand the part before the semicolon, but I don't clearly get what the rest of the sentence means.

Comment: Why do you say "get" when you mean "understand"?

Comment: This is clearly hyperbole. How long is it from one St. Patrick's day to the next?

Comment: @tchrist Why is the OP's use of "get" questionable? To me, that "get" shows a good command of idiomatic use of that word.

Answer (score 1):

> The professor's volubility knew no bounds;

Volubility is a rare word, meaning "ability to talk for a long time", and if it "knew no bounds", we mean (by personification)  that he was able to talk forever, or a very long time. This is hyperbole. It isn't really true that he could talk forever!

> he could talk through a hurricane

This is more hyperbole.  It would difficult to talk in a hurricane, but it claims that the professor could do this anyway.  Really it means "The professor could talk, even when other people would find it difficult".

> elaborate a point

When you are talking, you make "points" These are the facts that you claim. If you add details to the points, you "elaborate the point".

> from one St. Patrick's day to the next.

Ie. for one year.  This is hyperbolic, but it means he could "elaborate a point" for a very long time.  The use of St Patrick is due to this being an Irish text.